# Rails: How to handle a 503 error from external service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code calls an external service ([this gem, specifically](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-ruby))

The code in my controller is:

`query_one = GoogleSearchResults.new num: "1", q: "#{invite.invitee.name} + #{invite.invitee.guest_company}"`

From time to time, the service fails and Rollbar shows me:

```
Message
RuntimeError: Our services are overloaded, please try again later.

Traceback
OpenURI::HTTPError: 503 Service Unavailable
```

What code should I wrap the request line in so that it waits for one second to get a successful response back from the server, and if it fails, just moves on?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this...

```
begin
  attempts ||= 0
  query_one = GoogleSearchResults.new num: "1", q: "#{invite.invitee.name} + #{invite.invitee.guest_company}"
rescue OpenURI::HttpError
  if (attempts += 1) <= 1
    sleep 1
    retry
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write a try/catch block that looks for that specific exception and do exponential backoff.

```
# Exponential backoff in Ruby
begin
  make_request
rescue RequestError => e
  if retries <= max_retries
    retries += 1
    sleep 2 ** retries
    retry
  else
    raise "Timeout: #{e.message}"
  end
end
```

Comment: At least credit the author: https://gist.github.com/nathanl/c1e599640901d982cd3c